# LAN - troubleshooting

Tags: local-area-network, troubleshooting

I have 2 clients on my LAN that I'm trying to get to "see" each other. The first as follows

Computer1

```
IP 172.21.62.230
Subnet 255.255.255.224
Default gateway 172.21.62.225
Preferred DNS server 172.21.62.227
```

Computer2

```
IP 172.21.62.244
Subnet 255.255.255.224
Default gateway 172.21.62.225
Preferred DNS server 172.21.62.227
```

On computer1 I have a webserver and application server running. This works fine on http://localhost:8500 and on http://172.21.62.230:8500/ however I cannot ping 172.21.62.230 from computer2 ( I can connect to 172.21.62.230 using Remote Desktop).

I thought I would be able to connect the web server via browser from computer2 at http://172.21.62.244 but I cannot.

How can I work out whats going on?

Comment: This is much more of a question for Super User, not Server Fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows firewall blocks ping by default. Either enable ping to pass though or disable the firewall.

Comment: Doh! Windows firewall on computer1 needed the port 8500 opening